# Getting recurring meeting info from vsto addin

Tags: vb.net, outlook, ms-office, vsto, outlook-addin

I am creating an Outlook add-in using vb.net that creates multiple meeting invites based on a meeting created. I have most of the code working however what I can't figure out is how to to get the meeting information of a recurring meeting. Basically all I need to do is if the user creates a recurring meeting invite I want to copy that information and create another meeting by modifying the timinig.

I know I have to use Outlook.RecurrencePattern pattern but not sure how to get the information

TIA

Comment: Which RecurrencePattern property are you having problems with? Take a look at an existing recurring appointment with OutlookSpy - click Item button, go to the Functions tab, select GetRecurrencePattern, click Call.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, Apologies for the delayed response. thank you for the suggestion of Outlookspy. that help me solve this issue. all fixed now